# Most complete c++ facebook library

Tags: c++, facebook

I am looking for a c++ (or C) library to access facebook. I found some libraries doing some things, but they do not seams to be complete.

So, what is the most complete c++ library to access facebook?

EDIT

Found so far :
1) [C++ Facebook REST Client](http://projects.seligstein.com/facebook/)
2) [facebook-cpp-graph-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-cpp-graph-api/)

Comment: You can get from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333524/developing-a-facebook-app-with-c/10878077#10878077

Comment: @Mr.Black Your answered the wrong question. It would be more appropriate for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my perspective there is no true complete library as of late for Facebook in c++
best to find the ones you need as you go.

Though I recommend this Facebook api: [facebook graph api by meir yanovich](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-cpp-graph-api/)