# Facebook Graph API in C++

Tags: c++, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cocos2d-x

I am trying to integrate the Facebook into my game developed in C++ for iPhone and Android using Cocos2d-x. I couldn't find any good API for that in C++. Can anyone help on how to do this?

Comment: Use Objective-C instead.  Not for your game of course, but obviously you have to use objective-C to display things to the screen in iOS so you don't need to have a C++ API for Facebook.

Comment: I'm using cocos2d-x for development. That is I need to run the code in android also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not know about the iPhone but in Android i have done using the JNI call to java and from java i have called the facebook api,please check below code.

in $COCOS2DX_HOME\cocos2dx\platform\android
 CCApplication.h

```
void postMsgOnFacebook1(char *msg);
```

void CCApplication::postMsgOnFacebook(char *msg){

CCApplication.cpp

```
void CCApplication::postMsgOnFacebook(char *msg){

 JniMethodInfo minfo;

    if(JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(minfo, 
        "org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper", 
        "postMsgOnFacebook", 
        "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"))
    {
        jstring StringArg1 = minfo.env->NewStringUTF(msg);
        minfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(minfo.classID, minfo.methodID, StringArg1);
        minfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(StringArg1);
        minfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(minfo.classID);
    }
}
```

in java 
 org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper
  add new method

```
public static void postMsgOnFacebook(final String msg) {
     //facebook posting code here       
}
```

after this change please clean and build project
on any button click in game

```
 CCApplication::sharedApplication()->postMsgOnFacebook((char *)"facebook post");
```

i have done this in cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4.
if you need more help then please let me know

Thank you.

Comment: which SDK or API we have to link to eclips project for this? can u guide for that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290241/most-complete-c-facebook-library) I thing you can use it ;)

If this is written in C++ so you can use it with cocos2dx. But lookout for Qt you could extract their API :)